# No output from Golang Ginkgo BeforeSuite

Tags: go, ginkgo

I have the following [`Ginkgo`](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) test file:

```
package foo

import (
    "log"

    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
)

var _ = BeforeSuite(func() {
    log.Print("BeforeSuite")
})

var _ = AfterSuite(func() {
    log.Print("AfterSuite")
})

var _ = Describe("Foo", func() {
    log.Print("Describe")
})
```

When I run `ginkgo -r -v`, the test file runs, but the `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` do not appear to:

```
2016/03/16 09:23:17 Describe
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
```

The line `2016/03/16 09:23:17 Describe` shows that the `Describe` is running, but where is the output for `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite`?

I do not really care about the output, but in my real test (not the fragment above), database build up and tear down are not getting executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not invoking `RunSpecs`

```
func TestSo(t *testing.T) {
    RunSpecs(t, "My Test Suite")
}
```

Output then appears similar to

```
2016/03/16 07:16:05 Describe
Running Suite: So Suite
=======================
Random Seed: 1458137764
Will run 0 of 0 specs

2016/03/16 07:16:05 BeforeSuite
2016/03/16 07:16:05 AfterSuite

Ran 0 of 0 Specs in 0.000 seconds
SUCCESS! -- 0 Passed | 0 Failed | 0 Pending | 0 Skipped PASS

Ginkgo ran 1 suite in 1.211144437s
Test Suite Passed
```

Are you trying to run your actual tests in the `_suite_test.go` file?

Comment: I had the `RunSpecs` in a separate `_suite_test.go` file, but it appears that for ginkgo to work, `"github.com/onsi/gomega"` must be imported in the file containing the `BeforeSuite`, ... . I had to add a fake `It` and `Expect` to allow this (the import would not be "used", otherwise. At least that is what further testing seems to indicate. Thanks.